# -Xlint doesn't warn when the inferred type arg is widened too much

Tags: scala, warnings, compiler-flags

Tour of Scala: [Lower Type Bounds](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/lower-type-bounds.html) says compiling the code with `-Xlint` shoud give me a warning.

Here is my adaptation of the code. But I don't get any warning when I run `scalac -Xlint test.scala`. Why?

scalac version is 2.13.8

```
trait List[+A] {
  def prepend[B >: A](elem: B): NonEmptyList[B] = NonEmptyList(elem, this)
}

case class NonEmptyList[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

object Nil extends List[Nothing]

trait Bird
case class AfricanSwallow() extends Bird
case class EuropeanSwallow() extends Bird


object hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val africanSwallows: List[AfricanSwallow] = Nil.prepend(AfricanSwallow())
    val swallowsFromAntarctica: List[Bird] = Nil
    val someBird: Bird = EuropeanSwallow()

    val birds: List[Bird] = africanSwallows
    val someBirds = africanSwallows.prepend(someBird)
    val moreBirds = birds.prepend(EuropeanSwallow())
    val allBirds = africanSwallows.prepend(EuropeanSwallow())
    val error = moreBirds.prepend(swallowsFromAntarctica)    // List[Object]
  }
}
```

Comment: When I test with Scala 2.13.8 I get the warning - https://scastie.scala-lang.org/spHJWSxSSJGqz08JQ6qMPA . Your example also produces warnings https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1ixdcybTRoS6s1SJnVh2aw .

Comment: It works, I got the warning when testing your example with Scala 2.13.8.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's related to the scalac version. I think you should explicitly declare which warning you want lint to warn you. Like imagine this zero-ary eta expansion:

```scala
def myFunction(): Unit = ()

def accept(zeroAry: () => Unit): Unit = println("accepted")

accept(myFunction)
```

You need to explicitly tell lint to warn you when this happens:

```bash
> scalac -Xlint:eta-zero src/Main.scala

src/Main.scala:7: warning: An unapplied 0-arity method was eta-expanded (due to the expected type () => Unit), rather than applied to `()`.
Write myFunction() to invoke method myFunction, or change the expected type.
  accept(myFunction)
         ^
1 warning
```

Also, you may want the compiler to both warn you this, and detached function documentations, and some other ones, then you have to explicitly use them all together:

```bash
scalac -Xlint:eta-zero,doc-detached,some_other_warning,another_one src/Main.scala
```

Alternatively, you can use a wildcard so `scalac` will just enable lint for all the warnings:

```bash
scalac -Xlint:_ src/Main.scala
```